# adding different time in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm getting different time **(e.g. 05:25)** as a String from Arrayist and displaying in table. I need to add total time. But below code is throwing Exception as i'm trying to add String.

```
<c:set var="total" value="${0}"/> 
<c:forEach var="listItems" items="${requestScope.accTimeSheetList}">
<tr>
<td><c:out value='${listItems.myTime}'/></td>  (e.g. 05:25)
</tr>
<c:set var="total" value="${total + listItems.myTime}"/> 
</c:forEach>
 <td>
 ${total} 
</td>
```

Please help me out in solving this issue.

Comment: You can't add time like that. You should use proper utility classes to add time and can be done only in scriplet and not in jstl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend writing a back-end method in Java which performs this operation, as it isn't so trivial that you can do it in a few lines of JSTL code.

The [Joda](http://joda.sourceforge.net/) library is useful for such things. (In Java 8, the new java.time.* classes might be preferable).

```
public class TimeUtils {

  private static final PeriodFormatter HH_MM_FORMATTER = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .printZeroAlways()
    .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
    .appendHours()
    .appendSeparator(":")
    .printZeroAlways()
    .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
    .appendMinutes()
    .toFormatter();

  private static final PeriodFormatter DD_HH_MM_FORMATTER = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .printZeroAlways()
    .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
    .appendDays()
    .appendSeparator(":")
    .printZeroAlways()
    .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
    .appendHours()
    .appendSeparator(":")
    .printZeroAlways()
    .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
    .appendMinutes()
    .toFormatter();

  public static String addHhMmPeriods(List<String> hhMmPeriods) {
    Period total = new Period();
    for (String hhMmPeriod : hhMmPeriods) {
      total = total.plus(HH_MM_FORMATTER.parsePeriod(hhMmPeriod));
    }
    return total.normalizedStandard().toString(DD_HH_MM_FORMATTER);
  }
}
```

Java usage example:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    List<String> hhMmPeriods = new ArrayList<String>();
    hhMmPeriods.add("01:11");
    hhMmPeriods.add("11:00");
    hhMmPeriods.add("00:55");
    hhMmPeriods.add("21:47");

    System.out.println(TimeUtils.addHhMmPeriods(hhMmPeriods)); // => 01:10:53
  }
```

You could then wrap this method in a JSP tag library, or just use a JSP scriptlet to call the Java method directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scriplet in this way and make sure you import all required packages in the page

```
<%
 String myTime = "05:25";
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
 Date d = df.parse(myTime); 
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTime(d);
 cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 20); //adding 20 mins
 String newTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
%>
```

You just need to write proper logic to your case based on is thexample